# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, object

hello i want to know what i am doing wrong that i am getting this error here is my controller and view

```
$invoice_specs = invoice::find($id);
$view=view('admin.invoices.pdf',compact('invoice_specs',$invoice_specs));
```

and here is where i have my view

```
    <table class="table ">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>description</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($invoice_specs as $invoice_spec)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$invoice_spec->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$invoice_spec->title}}</td>
                        <td>{{$invoice_spec->description}}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and finally here is when i dd $invoice_specs

```
#attributes: array:5 [▼
"id" => 3
"title" => "سومین فاکتور"
"description" => "سومین فاکتور"
"created_at" => "2018-06-12 21:31:57"
"updated_at" => "2018-06-12 21:31:57"]


 #original: array:5 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "title" => "سومین فاکتور"
    "description" => "سومین فاکتور"
    "created_at" => "2018-06-12 21:31:57"
    "updated_at" => "2018-06-12 21:31:57"
  ]
```

Comment: I would recommend not using `find($id)` and instead using `findOrFail($id)` as a general rule of thumb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the static find method you call to retrieve data from database, only returns a single model not a collection. So when in your view you try to use foreach with the variable `$invoice_specs` it in fact doesn't loop through collection of models.

In [Laravel's docs on Eloquent and retrieving single models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) you can see that the `find` and `first` methods only return a single model, which you cannot use into a foreach loop.

[This section of Laravel's docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-models) explains how to retrieve models and how to work with them. I suggest you to read that first :)

So currently what you can do if you want to display a single model is get rid of the `foreach` loop in your view and in your controller you should rename variable `invoice_specs` to `invoice_spec`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `invoice_specs` is a single Model, you may not want to iterate over it using `foreach` you may simply try accessing `id` property directly on `invoice_specs`.

But, it seems like you want to find a number of invoices, but you are using `find()` to find by `primary key` in which case you will get only one or no result.

Please provide more clarity to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should not here iterate over the result. You should do this way in your HTML

```
<table class="table ">
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>id</th>
     <th>name</th>
     <th>description</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>{{$invoice_specs->id}}</td>
     <td>{{$invoice_specs->title}}</td>
     <td>{{$invoice_specs->description}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `foreach` loop there, Its not a collection.
Simply use `$invoice_spec->id` straight away. That's it.

We use `foreach` or `forelse` for a collection.